# Convert BigDecimal to the opposite of scale = 2

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have a bigdecimal but I want to convert to the opposite of setScale = 2.

> 1 -> 0.01
>
> 123 -> 1.23
>
> 5555555 -> 55555.55

How can I do that?

Comment: `BigDecimal t = new BigDecimal(value);
        BigDecimal result = t.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100));`

Comment: Why not setScale(-2)?

Comment: You just want to divide by 100? Why don't you simply say so, instead of circumscribing it with "opposite of scale = 2"?

Comment: @LouisWassermann: that would turn 1 into 100, 123 into 12300 etc., which is not the desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

**Exmple :**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BigDecimal{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int   number= in.nextInt();
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(number); 
    BigDecimal rslt = bd.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100));
    System.out.println(rslt );


}

}
```

Output  :

```
1
0.01
```